# How to prove $a- \epsilon < x \leq a$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

QS1:

### Let $a \in \mathbb{R},\, A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $a=supA$. Proof $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x \in A: a - \epsilon <x \leq a$?

QS2:
Let $a \in \mathbb{R},\, A \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $a$ is a upper bound of $A$ and $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists x \in A: a - \epsilon <x \leq a$.
Proof: $$a =supA$$
Thank everyone^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QS1:If $a=supA$ then it is clear that $x\le a$ for all $x\in A$. Now we prove $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists x\in A$ such that $a-\epsilon<x$. Indeed, we assume by contradiction that $\exists\epsilon>0$, $\forall x\in A$, $a-\epsilon\ge x$. Then, we deduce $a-\varepsilon\ge supA=a$ (since $a-\epsilon$ is an upper bound of $A$), or $\epsilon\le 0$. This is a contradiction.

QS2:Since $x\le a$ for all $x\in A$, we deduce $sup A\le a$. If $a>supA$, then for $\epsilon=a-supA>0$, by assumption, there exists a $x\in A$ such that $a-\epsilon<x$. This leads to $a-(a-supA)<x$, or equivalently $supA<x$, which is a contradiction. So, we must have $supA=a$.

Comment: thanks! :) Are you Vietnamese?